# How to make two different login systems in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii. I just need two login page. One for Super-Admin and another for Sub-Admin. I created Super-Admin login page and it is successful. My Super-Admin path is 127.0.0.1/ticketing/adminLogin. My Sub-Admin path is 127.0.0.1/ticketing/login. I had created crud app for adminLogin page. Now i am using default login page for Sub-Admin. But i gave all the proper model name and actions. But my Sub-Admin login page is checking values from Super-Admin table and not from Sub-Admin table. Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi Provide your code first with structure of table.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as you said you have created a complete new crud for `admin` and `sub admin` then you can also create a new `SubadminUserIdentity` in components which extend `CUserIdentity` and in login model of sub admin use `SubadminUserIdentity`in `authenticate` and `login` `function`

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for your reply. I got an answer. I made a silly mistake. I called the same authenticate function for Super-Admin and Sub-Admin. Now i make two authenticate functions and it works.